# Yii model not bulid relation automatically using gii

Tags: php, mysql, yii, gii

HI i never faced this type of problem. Please clarify me when i did wrong. I tried to generate 2 model which have relation but it didn't come in models. Here are the Db structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `property` (
    `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ListPrice` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `ListingURL` text NOT NULL,
    `ProviderName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `ProviderURL` text NOT NULL,
    `modificationTimestamp` text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
    `loc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `latitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `longitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`loc_id`),
    KEY `property_id` (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

--
-- Constraints for table `location`
--
ALTER TABLE `location`
ADD CONSTRAINT `location_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`property_id`)
     REFERENCES `property` (`property_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

In model no relation in there :

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
    );
}
```

Comment: I just tried running your three SQL queries and checked the "Location" model with Gii.  The relation is in there.  I get `'property' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Property', 'property_id'),`.

Comment: strange. it's the first time when i face this.

Comment: Does your database use InnoDB by default?

Comment: i never understood how to make relations on database, so i use a designer that makes them for me, you could try `MySQL Workbench`

Comment: Yes @Jerome , by default it's InnoDB

Comment: @SRana - Can you confirm that you've selected the option to "Build Relations" in gii?  Are you also using the latest version of the framework?

Comment: @jerome- the yii version is 1.1.15 and "Build Relations" is selected by default.

Comment: @SRana - I'm sorry, it seems like it should work based on all the evidence you presented.  The only thing you're doing different from how I build my queries is that I add the constraint as part of the `CREATE TABLE` as opposed to altering the table after the fact, but I really  can't see that as the problem.  If gii can't see the relations, it may be because the relation is not created properly in MySQL.  If you used a GUI client to try manually adding rows, do you get errors creating a location record if you supplied a property id that doesn't exist in the property table?

Answer (score 2):

This happens sometimes with the gii tool. What you need to do is to comment the relation in the table itself. gii misses the rleationship sometimes but mostly picks it up if available in the comment. So, modify your tables and comment the foreign key as below, it should work.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location` (
    `loc_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `property_id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Foreign Key (property_id) references property(property_id )',
    `latitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    `longitude` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
    PRIMARY KEY (`loc_id`),
    KEY `property_id` (`property_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: I had three relations and put in one comment to test the theory and Gii picked up all three.  Thanks!